# A simple question about normal subgroups of finite groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H_1 \trianglelefteq G$. If $H_2 \leq G$, with $|H_1| = |H_2|$, can we state that $H_2 \trianglelefteq G$? If it is false in general, is the same statement true supposing furthermore that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are isomorphic?

Answer (score 6):

No.
Pick your favourite example of $A\le B$ with $A\not\lhd B$. Then consider $G=A\times B$ and let $H_1$ be the $A$ that is the first factor and $H_2$ the $A$ contained in the second.

Comment: I am going to take $\tau = (23)$ in the not abelian group of order $6$, $D_3$. Then the order of $\tau$ is $2$ and $\langle \tau \rangle$ is a subgroup, but not normal in $D_3$. Then can I take $G = \langle \tau \rangle \times D_3$? This group must have order $12$. Then do $H_1 = \langle \tau \rangle \times \{Id\} \cong {\mathbb{Z}}_2$ and $H_2 = \{Id\} \times \langle \tau \rangle \cong {\mathbb{Z}}_2$ work as counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

For the first argument there is a well-known which results: If $$|G/H_1|=2$$ where $|G|<\infty$ so, $|G/H_2|=2$ so $H_2$ would be a normal subgroup. So this, as you stated, may not be true in general. Moreover, we could have the first statement true when $p$ be the smallest prime number which divides $|G|$ and $|G/H|=p$.

Comment: You do not need to assume $|G|<\infty$ for this result. The proof goes: If $H$ has index two in $G$ then there are two left cosets $\{H, aH\}$, two right cosets $\{H, Ha\}$, and left and right cosets are the same sets. Hence, $aH=Ha$, and so $H\lhd G$.

Comment: @user1729: Thanks for consideration! Yes you are right. Maybe I wanted to walk in OP's track who had assumed the group is finite.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take the group of all $2\times2$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_3$ (or any other finite field whose characteristic is not $2$). Now, consider $H_1=\{\pm\operatorname{Id}\}$ and$$H_2=\left\{\operatorname{Id},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Several subgroups of the symmetric group $S_4$ are isomorphic to the Klein Four-Group, but only one of them is a normal subgroup.

Comment: And if I suppose furthermore that $|G| \leq 15$?

Comment: @joseabp91 Sure. $S_2\times S_3$ is a group of order $12$ which has seven subgroups of order two, and just one of them is normal.

Answer (score 0):

It is true also if $H_1$ is a Sylow subgroup of $G$ (this is the *Second Sylow theorem*).